# How to feed multiple values of X data for each Y to a TensorFlow NN

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a two sets of numpy array data of dimensions 36*3. Each row of both arrays corresponds to the same Y value. I need to feed in each row for numpy array 1 into a regression NN to generate a value, and then sum all of these. This needs to be repeated for numpy array 2. The final prediction for the single Y value, is the difference between the two sums of predictions.

I am unsure how to feed these rows of x data (3 input nodes) values into a X placeholder, for each y value into a Y placeholder to then be run in a TF session. As the entire code below only corresponds to one datapoint in effect; the function get_dataset(1) gives this.This is how one datapoint is loaded currently.

I am wondering how others would approach this fitting problem. Essentially I do not know how to format the x data. There is more than one input per Y value.

```
data = get_dataset(1)  # 36*6 np array corresponding to one Y value

ideal_data = data[:,[0,1,4]] # ideal and displaced data are in these columns (0,1) and (2,3)
ideal_data = ideal_data.tolist() #flatten

displaced_data = data[:,[2,3,4]]
displaced_data = displaced_data.tolist()

y = data[0][5]

y_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(y)

for i in range(36): # get each row i.e. X(i) datapoints
  ideal_data_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(ideal_data[i])
  displaced_data_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(displaced_data[i])
```

My regression NN is currently defined as the following function, with an X placeholder:

```
with tf.name_scope("Training_Neural_Network"):
#Training Computation
  def training_multilayer_perceptron(X, weights, biases): #dropout should only be used during training, not during evaluation
    with tf.name_scope("Layer1"):
      layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, weights['W1']), biases['b1'])
      layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
      layer_1 = tf.nn.dropout(layer_1,keep_prob)
    with tf.name_scope("Layer2"):
      layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['W2']), biases['b2'])
      layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)
      layer_2 = tf.nn.dropout(layer_2,keep_prob)
    with tf.name_scope("Layer3"):
      out_layer = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['W3']), biases['b3'])
      return out_layer
```

P.s this is the first question I have posted on SO, so any comments on how I can make my question better would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me... How many values do you feed to the network? How do you compute those values? Can you show an example of the usage?

Comment: Is the question how to split the data into `x_array` and `y_array`, or how to feed it into the NN?

Comment: Hi, I need to feed 72 x-data values through a feed-forward NN, and sum the predictions. This sum is then used to compute the error in the following fashion; error Y - sum(pred_i). I believe it is a sort of delayed back-propagation. I am struggling as in TF, one usually just has one x-data point per y-data point, but in this case that is not true.

Answer (score 1):

I probably don't understand the question right, but I have implemented something very similar in my MA thesis so I'm gonna show you the code (with good structured comments) below.

```
df = read_excel('Train_Data.xlsx')

# convert dataframe into array
data = np.asarray(df, dtype=np.int64)

# train data (x) contains all rows and all columns except the last
x = data[:, :-1]
# label data (y) contains all rows and only the last column 
y = data[:, -1]

# label data is reshaped to fit the right format
y = np.reshape(y, [y.shape[0], 1])

# both datasets are shuffled to simplify split of train and test data
permutation = np.random.permutation(x.shape[0])
x = x[permutation]
y = y[permutation]

# test data ratio is determined
test_size = 0.1

# train data is sliced from list of total data, test data equals the rest
num_test = int(test_size * len(data))
X_train = x[:-num_test]
X_test = x[-num_test:]

# the same applies for the label values
Y_train = y[:-num_test]
Y_test = y[-num_test:]

[...]

# defining placeholder variables for model
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 7])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 1])
```

The placeholder definition for x takes the shape of your input data, so if you have like 36*6 = 216 features which correspond to 1 label, you will set

```
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 216])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 1])
```

And later you fill the placeholders in your session (I have implemented it with batches)

```
# launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(total_len/batch_size)
        # loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch-1):
            batch_x = X_train[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
            batch_y = Y_train[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
            # run optimization (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            _, c, p = sess.run([optimizer, cost, pred], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                                   y: batch_y})
```

Comment: Hi Luciano - unfortunately there are not 216 input features. There are three. The 36, corresponds to 36 rows of x-data, per one y data. That is why in the ideal_data, and displaced_data, there are only three columns - each is a descriptor for each x-data point.

Comment: can't you just flatten the 36 items into an array? That would be much easier to deal with than a 3*36 matrix as input for one label value.

Comment: Yes, thats a good idea - but have you any idea how to run each of the 36 items through the NN, and sum the outputs? Also this would need to be repeated for the other 3*36 array, as the final prediction is the difference between the two summations.

Comment: So are you performing a regression or classification? Because for a regression you would predict a label for the difference, which you could calculate via excel or pandas for the first two 3*36 arrays. so you can calculate it manually, input the first two 3*36 arrays as an flattened array as your features in the neural net and give it the calculated difference as label data.

Comment: The Scheme is as follows: Y = sum(NN,ideal) - sum(NN,displaced). Where the sum is over each of the 36 items for both the ideal and displaced arrays, of which need to be fed through the regression NN. The error is the difference between Y, and the term shown.